# video is starting very slow to play ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, video, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

i have local video which going to play in my app. But in my browser its working fine. But when i try to see in device. My video is blank and after 10 to 20 seconds only my video is playing. help me out. Whats i am doing wrong ?

my code :

**HTML**

Once i click this one model pop up will open and it will play the video :

**video popup.html**

```
<div class="modal transparent fullscreen-player" ng-click="closeModal()">


    <video ng-src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" class="centerme" controls="controls" autoplay></video>

    <span class="ion-android-close nv"  ng-click="closeModal()"></span>


</div>
```

**My JS**

```
$scope.playVideo = function() {
  $scope.showModal('templates/video-popover.html');
}

$scope.showModal = function(templateUrl) {
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(templateUrl, {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function(modal) {
            $ionicLoading.show({

  duration: 3000
});
            $scope.modal = modal;
            $scope.modal.show();
        });
    }

    // Close the modal
    $scope.closeModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.hide();
        $scope.modal.remove()
    };
```

Please help me out. why its taking 10 - 20 sec blank and then its playing video.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most audio & video element issues with Android are non-existant when using Crosswalk (Chromium webview) with your Ionic project.

Disclaimer: Adding Crosswalk increases app binary size.

Make a backup before adding Crosswalk to your project.

ionic browser add crosswalk

Comment: i did but i am getting error `browser is not a valid task`

Comment: Instead of <video> tag, try using HTML <iframe> tag to embed another document within the current HTML. See the example below:

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  tag, try using HTML  tag to embed another document within the current HTML. See the example below:

Read about iframe here: [w3school iframe link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: can you please help me for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496455/how-to-show-pdf-file-in-ionic-app-with-out-download